# Using a Perl module with empty parentheses

Tags: perl

I'm trying to learn Perl and understand something about `use` and modules.

(Assume `use strict; use warnings;`)

I understand that `use File::Find;` loads all the subroutines of the module.

I understand that `use File::Find qw(find);` loads only the `find` subroutine of the module (although other subroutines my be used via `File::Find::finddepth`).

So what does `File::Find ();` do? Specifically, why the empty parens?

Comment: Perhaps you could try reading the documentation for "use" - http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

tl;dr : It says not to export anything instead of the default.

long version:

File::Find has `our @EXPORT = qw(find finddepth);`, so those subs are exported by default. If we just use the module and then try to call `find` it errors because I didn't pass it the right arguments to `find` but `find` *does* exist.

```
quentin@workstation:~ # perl
use File::Find;
find();

no &wanted subroutine given at /Users/david/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.1/lib/5.16.1/File/Find.pm line 1064.
```

Passing a list in the `use` statement overrides the defaults and exports only the subs that you ask for. An empty list means that none will be exported and it will error because `find` doesn't exist. Such:

```
quentin@workstation:~ # perl
use File::Find ();
find();

Undefined subroutine &main::find called at - line 2.
```

Answer (score 1):

> So what does File::Find (); do? Specifically, why the empty parens?

In short, you **require**-ing this module and calling `File::Find::import` to import functions (like `find` and `finddepth` in your example). So empty brackets mean you dont want import anything, and implicitly forbid to import any default symbols.